# Can't send ether to the contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, gas-limit

I'm using My ether wallet on Ropsten, Brave(Metamask Ropsten) and Remix Ropsten Injected Web3. The first transaction was successful (0.5 ether received),https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x471dDAF0c395c2fA0A97e9ACA175E4757362CbF6. My ether wallet adjusted automatically gas limit from 21000 to 122206. The next transactions unfortunately fail because gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction.Contract execution [Reverted]. Gas limit No adjusted by My ether wallet this time.
Functions on Remix:unpause,transferOwnership,buy,fallback,transferfrom,transfer,setTokenOffering failing - gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction.
Where is the problem ? On my computer whether on my code here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x471ddaf0c395c2fa0a97e9aca175e4757362cbf6#code
 Any help is really appreciate to finally solve the gas error problems.Robert

Comment: How are you sending the Ether? I don't see any `payable` functions? Are you sure that's your code and not another token's which you have borrowed?

Comment: Hello Lauri, I'm sending from My ether wallet ropsten to crowdsale contract here https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x471ddaf0c395c2fa0a97e9aca175e4757362cbf6#code.

Comment: Payable function is in crowdsale contract. Token contract here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xaa3248ab8c97866ea91a9ceda821aaa95ed457d4#code

Comment: Without analyzing how the code exactly works there might be a bug in the code. I remember someone else also having similar problems with the same crowdsale here. Or maybe it has expired or funding cap has been exceeded or something similar?

Comment: Strange is the first transaction was successful (0.5 ether received),https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x471dDAF0c395c2fA0A97e9ACA175E4757362CbF6 , then gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction came up. Where is the problem?

Comment: Hello Lauri You was right the bug was in the code  if (amountRaised <= fundingGoal) {  should be  if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal) {